# What happens if I don't give Moustache Girl a time piece?

Tags: a-hat-in-time

***(Spoilers for the ending of A Hat in Time)***

In the final cutscene of A Hat in Time, [the player is asked to make a choice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XYJeP.jpg).

> Drop a Time Piece down and lend the red hooded girl some Time Piece power to defeat the Mafia? (You may not be able to make it all the way home.)

I chose to give Moustache Girl the time piece, which resulted in Hat Kid throwing down an hourglass, saying goodbye to her Earth friends, then blasting off towards her home.

What would have happened if I had kept the time piece for myself? Would it have changed the game's ending?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Aside from not sending a Time Piece to the planet, nothing visibly changes. The same credits sequence and end of game cutscenes play. The game never makes it clear whether you get home or Mustache Girl uses the Time Piece successfully one way or another...

Comment: Personally, I like the ending this way. The ambiguity gives a lot to think about, which is more sophisticated then I expected from the plot of a collectathon.